# Python selenium not taking tables , please review

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

so below the main code i have written, website is https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list'

# Set up Selenium options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Navigate to the webpage
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Find all table elements on the page using the 'tag_name' locator strategy
tables = driver.find_elements('tag name', 'table')

# Iterate through the tables to find the one you need
table = None
for t in tables:
    if 'list-group-item' in t.get_attribute('class'):
        table = t
        break

if table:
    # Extract the table data
    data = []
    for row in table.find_elements('tag name', 'tr'):
        rowData = []
        for cell in row.find_elements('tag name', 'td'):
            rowData.append(cell.text)
        data.append(rowData)

    # Store the table data in a DataFrame
    results = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Print the results
    print(results)
else:
    print('Table not found.')

# Close the Selenium driver
driver.quit()
```

So the above code is not working to get details of the table , i am not even looping it to get details of others pages yet, please check and let me know where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using selenium? You can just have pandas parse the tables. Will take a while to go through all the pages though.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list/p-1-company.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
last_page = soup.find_all('a', text=lambda text: text and '>>' in text)[0]['href']
match = int(re.search(r'p-(\d+)',last_page).group(1))

dfs = []
tot = match
for page in range(1, match+1):
    url = f'https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list/p-{page}-company.html'
    print(f'Page: {page} of {tot}')
    dfs.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
    
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: You are right, my bad. i thought it was dynamic java tables:

Udated the code i used now and again really thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake. Find_Elements does not take 2 strings, but a By option and a string:

```
tables = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
```

Comment: Hi, tried that, but it giving below error:

"AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'"

Comment: @KadamJain Take a good look at my code. I did Not write find_elements_by_tag_name, I wrote driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')

Comment: I am pretty new at coding, i took this completely and changed it in my code, but is giving error, the one i mentioned above.